# datePicker with maximum year current year

Tags: ios, objective-c, datepicker, uidatepicker

I am developing an iPhone app where user can save `Birthdays` along with other data.

For Birthday I am trying to add a `UIDatePicker` that shows date, month and year. for the year I want to set the picker maximum range to current year and after that an empty slot (just like the contact/phone app - add birthday option).

Is there anyway I can do that using `UIDatePicker` or do I have to use custom picker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the property `maximumDate` with current Date object. It will not allow the user to select any date beyond today. However it will not show the empty slots but grayed out slots. If user will try to select it, picker will again set with max possible date.

```
datePicker. maximumDate = [NSDate date];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Apurv. so does it mean that its not possible to have the empty slot in datePicker?

Comment: Yes, it is not possible.